# How to calculate the number of days worked by an employee in a month in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with the list of staff and the dates they came to work. I want to calculate the number of days each employee went to work in that month.

[image]

I want to have each Id with the number of days they went to work in a different sheet

Comment: Have you checked any of the workdays functions provided in Excel? or networkdays.intl() ? Try them as they are comprehensive and will include holidays you can provide in the form of a list.

Answer (score 1):

On the Power Pivot tab in Excel, add your table to the Data Model. When the Power Pivot window opens, close it.

On your spreadsheet, Insert Pivot Table from Data Model. Put Ids in the Rows field and Dates in the Values field. Summarize the Dates values as Distinct Count.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is located in a sheet called Sheet1, paste this in a new sheet:

| Year & month & id | Working days | Year & month & id & working days | Year & month & id & working days (compacted) | Year | Month | Id | Working days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A2),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A2)*10^8+Sheet1!B2*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"") | =IF(B2="","",A2+B2) | =IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D2))),"") | =IFERROR(MID(D2,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D2,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D2,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D2,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A3),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A3)*10^8+Sheet1!B3*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A3,A3)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A3),"") | =IF(B3="","",A3+B3) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D3))) | =IFERROR(MID(D3,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D3,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D3,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D3,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A4),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A4)*10^8+Sheet1!B4*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A4,A4)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A4),"") | =IF(B4="","",A4+B4) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D4))) | =IFERROR(MID(D4,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D4,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D4,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D4,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A5),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A5)*10^8+Sheet1!B5*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A5,A5)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A5),"") | =IF(B5="","",A5+B5) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D5))) | =IFERROR(MID(D5,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D5,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D5,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D5,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A6),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A6)*10^8+Sheet1!B6*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A6,A6)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A6),"") | =IF(B6="","",A6+B6) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D6))) | =IFERROR(MID(D6,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D6,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D6,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D6,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A7),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A7)*10^8+Sheet1!B7*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A7,A7)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A7),"") | =IF(B7="","",A7+B7) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D7))) | =IFERROR(MID(D7,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D7,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D7,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D7,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A8),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A8)*10^8+Sheet1!B8*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A8,A8)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A8),"") | =IF(B8="","",A8+B8) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D8))) | =IFERROR(MID(D8,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D8,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D8,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D8,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A9),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A9)*10^8+Sheet1!B9*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A9,A9)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A9),"") | =IF(B9="","",A9+B9) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D9))) | =IFERROR(MID(D9,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D9,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D9,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D9,2)*1,"") |
| =RIGHT(YEAR(Sheet1!A10),2)*10^10+MONTH(Sheet1!A10)*10^8+Sheet1!B10*10^2 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A10,A10)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A10),"") | =IF(B10="","",A10+B10) | =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)))/(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C))<>""),ROWS($C$2:D10))) | =IFERROR(MID(D10,1,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D10,3,2)*1,"") | =IFERROR(MID(D10,5,6)*1,"") | =IFERROR(RIGHT(D10,2)*1,"") |